# Recommended practice for editing a model in MVC

Tags: macos, cocoa, model-view-controller

I am using an NSTableView to allow editing of a small (<15KB) xml file that maintains budget data in a financial app. It is necessary to "ask" the view for information regarding user intent in order to edit the model. If asking a view for data is not consistent with MVC, what is the best practice for model editing?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on what you're asking from the view?

Answer (score 0):

Discovered that I don't need to ask the view anything. Table edits of existing elements are handled by the framework and adding/deleting elements is very well described in [this link](http://www.macdevcenter.com/pub/a/mac/2001/08/10/cocoa.html?page=3).